# Correctly handling s:url tag with parameters -security implications?

Tags: struts2

In my .jsp page I have

```
<s:url id="ecu" value="ecu-info-detail">
        <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
        <s:param name="ecuName" value="name"></s:param>
        <s:param name="ajax" value="true"></s:param>
    </s:url>
```

which I use in a sj:a tag thus;

```
<li class="vMenuItem"><sj:a href="%{ecu}" requestType="GET" targets="detail"><s:property value="description"/></sj:a></li>
```

when this link is clicked the url generated is in the format;

```
my.domain.com?id="01"&amp;ecuName="foo"&amp;ajax="true"
```

so the parameters ecuName and ajax do not get set on the action. Now I can get around this by simply adding the attribute escapeAmp="true" to the s:url definition. However, because the Struts 2 default is to escape the ampersand and because I cannot be the only person using multiple s:param tags, I am concerned that escapeAmp="true" may not be the correct way of handling this situation and I'm creating a security hole.

Is this the correct way to deal with this situation, and if not, how should I deal with it?

Regards

Comment: which version of JQuery plugin you are using?

Comment: there was the issue register with Jquery plugin and problem is not about S2 but the way plugin work.here is the link for issue http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=51

Comment: That was for version 1.8.1 and was closed in 2010

Comment: it was closed with discussion that you need to escape that html and i can't see any security issue with this.

Comment: Could you make that your answer so I can mark answer accepted please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer as per the discussion in the comment section.Same issue was reported in the plugin development team [url paramerters escaped](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=51).

Same issue was closed with a discussion that we need to escape that html in order for this to work with Jquery tags.For more details please read the filed bug ticket.